# How to identify object that is deleted from a collection (array)?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have following code to handle pull to refresh response

```
let copyData = data.reversed() // it is pull to refresh response (load page 1)
for (_,element) in copyData.enumerated() {
    let foundElement = allObjects.filter{$0.id == element.id} // Find  element in main array
    if let firstElement = foundElement.first, let index =   allObjects.index(of: firstElement) {
        allObjects[index] = element // Replace if found
    } else {
        allObjects.insert(element, at: 0) // Insert if not found 
    }
}


self.arrayPosts = allObjects
```

Where `data` is codable class which is API response of pull to refresh. `allObjects` is preloaded data with pagination

**Question** :  Suppose In `allObjects` i have 50 Object (5 Pages of 10 ID is (1 to 50)) 
User pull to refresh And I load first Page from API (ID 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11) then how to identify which object is deleted **(8,9)** ?

Should I compare `allObjects` 's 10th index with `data`'s 10th index object's ID ?

Is it better way to handle this ? Please suggest

Comment: You would need to store the older copy and compare it with the newer one.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thanks for reading , I have old copy  Could you please explain how can I do it. Issue is actually pull to refresh loads first page which  will return 10 or less object so how would I compare with main array  which as 50 object ?

Comment: You should have a copy of the _older_ first page and compare it with the _newer_ one.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri For me it doesn't seems to be a better idea. I need to maintain two array and update each doesn't seems to be a better idea. I am thinking about sorting both array in same order and then I can compare both as I got max id of first page I receive

Comment: I was giving you a generic answer. For your case. Since you know the order you would just use the `allObjects` for comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't compare pages (i.e. 10 items at a time) - if an item is added/deleted the pages will get out of sync, and you'll end up with missing / duplicate objects.

Presumably your objects are sorted by some key / date, etc.

- Take the value of the key in your last downloaded object.
- Copy all the existing objects with keys <= that last key into a new array.
- Compare your downloaded array against this sub-array.
- Objects in the downloaded array that are not in the sub-array should be removed.

Comment: First step I will add new object to main array like main array(1 to 50) downloaded array (70,1,2,4) 3 is deleted So i will add first 70 to main array so now it is (70,1,to 50) then  will compare 1,2,3,4,70 with 1,2,4,70 Correct ?

Comment: Well, it depends what your field your objects are sorted on - you need to use that to decide what to compare

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I did it !!

Answer (score 0):

Here How I handle this. Code is quite complex for first time read but added comments to understand it

```
func handleResponse(page:Int,isForRefersh:Bool = false, data:Array<InspirePost>) {


        guard data.count != 0 else {
            // Check if we are requesting data from pull to referesh and First page is empty then we don't have data to show change state to empty

            if self.arrayPosts.count == 0  || (isForRefersh && page == 1) {
                self.state = .empty
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {
                self.state = .populated(posts: self.arrayPosts)

            }
            return
        }

        // Now we need to check if data called by referesh control then
        //1) Replace object in array other wise just append it.

        var allObjects = self.state.currentPost

        if isForRefersh {
            // If both array Has same number of element i.e both has page one loaded
            if data.count >= allObjects.count {
                allObjects = data
            } else {
                let copyData = data.reversed()
                for (_,element) in copyData.enumerated() {
                    if let index = allObjects.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == element.id}) {
                        allObjects[index] = element // Replace if found
                    } else {
                        allObjects.insert(element, at: 0) // Insert if not
                    }

                }

                let minID = data.min(by: {$0.id ?? 0 < $1.id ?? 0})?.id

                // DELETE item
                let copyAllObject = allObjects
                for (_,element) in copyAllObject.enumerated() {
                    guard let id = element.id, id >=  minID  ?? 0 else {
                        continue
                    }
                    if !data.contains(element) {
                        if let indexInMainArray = allObjects.index(where: {$0.id == id}) {
                            allObjects.remove(at: indexInMainArray)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //When we pull to refersh check the curent state

            switch self.state {
            case .empty,.populated : // if empty or populated set it as populated (empty if no record was avaiable then pull to refersh )
                self.state = .populated(posts: allObjects)
            case .error(_, let  lastState) : // If there was error before pull to referesh handle this
                switch lastState {
                case .empty ,.populated: // Before the error tableview was empty or popluated with data
                    self.state = .populated(posts: allObjects)
                case .loading,.error: // Before error there was loading data (There might more pages if it was in loading so we doing paging state ) or error
                    self.state = .paging(posts: allObjects, nextPage: page + 1)
                case .paging(_,let nextPage): // Before error there was paging then we again change it to paging
                    self.state = .paging(posts: allObjects, nextPage: nextPage)


                }
            case .loading: // Current state was loading (this might not been true but for safety we are adding this)
                self.state = .paging(posts: allObjects, nextPage: page + 1)
            case .paging(_,let nextPage): // if there was paging on going don't break anything
                self.state = .paging(posts: allObjects, nextPage: nextPage)

            }

            self.arrayPosts = allObjects



        } else {
            allObjects.append(contentsOf: data)
            self.isMoreDataAvailable = data.count >= self.pageLimit

            if self.isMoreDataAvailable {

                self.state = .paging(posts: allObjects, nextPage: page + 1)

            } else {
                self.state = .populated(posts: allObjects)
            }
            self.arrayPosts = self.state.currentPost
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Where I have

```
indirect enum PostListStatus {
    case loading
    case paging(posts:[InspirePost],nextPage:Int)
    case populated(posts:[InspirePost])
    case error (error:String,lastState:PostListStatus) // keep last state for future if we need to know about data or state
    case empty


    var currentPost:[InspirePost] {
        switch self {
        case .paging(let posts ,  _):
            return posts
        case .populated( let posts):
            return posts
        case .error( _, let  oldPost) :
            switch oldPost {
            case .paging(let posts ,  _):
                return posts
            case .populated( let posts):
                return posts
            default:
                return []
            }

        default:
            return []
        }
    }

    var nextPage : Int {
        switch  self {
        case .paging(_, let page):
            return page
        default:
            return 1
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily inefficient. With `filter` and `index` you are searching the array **twice** which could be very expensive. Replace the lines `let foundElement = allObjects.filter{$0.id == element.id}` and `if let firstElement = foundElement.first, let index =   allObjects.index(of: firstElement) {` with `if let index = allObjects.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == element.id}) {`

Comment: @vadian Thanks for very useful comment will do it

Answer (score -1):

You may make `set` for both `allObjects` and `data`. Then use `subtracting(_:)` method in `set` to find the missing one.
Remove those missing ones from the main array and use it. Once you have correct main array elements, page them while displaying.

Comment: Both contains different number of elements main array contains 50 elements and data has 10 elements so subtracting will always return 40  or less elements